# weird behavior in android onclick debug mode true false

Tags: java, android, onclick

I found a weird behavior(in my opinion).

I created an activity with a simple click action `onLogon(View view)`.
(No onclick listener!) and in my `layout.xml`, I just added a button and used `android:onClick="onLogon"`

Running this in debug mode on my android phone (kitkat) was no problem.
But as soon as I deployed it without debug mode, this gave errors.

I had to change the onLogon(View view) with an onclick listener to something like this.

```
Button mSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogon);
        mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                attemptLogin();
            }
        });
```

This last way of handling click events seems to work in debug, deploy and when deploying through the play store.

I understand why the onclick handler is the prefered way. I don't understand the difference in behavior between debug and non debug.

Maybe someone can explain this??

Comment: Please share the code for `onLogon()`

Answer (score 0):

You should check this [Button click events](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) you are providing two click events.

Comment: Sorry i think you mis-understood. When i used the onclickhandler i removed the android:onclick. After i found out the direct android:onClick didn't work i removed that one and used the onclicklistener instead of the android:onclick